# Classes & Defines in Puppet

Tags: puppet

Although I know the immediate solution to a problem I was facing yesterday (thanks to the folks over at IRC #puppet), I still don't understand how it solved the problem, or rather what's the fundamental difference between classes and defines in this particular scenario:

**The original define, which was incorrect:**

```
define srv($name,$enable="true",$ensure="running",$provider="runit",$hasstatus="true",$hasrestart="true"){

                exec {"sleep 5": path=>"/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin", before=>Service["$name"],}

                service{"$name":

                    enable=>$enable,
                    ensure=>$ensure,
                    provider=>$provider,
                    hasstatus=>$hasstatus,
                    hasrestart=>$hasrestart,
                } 
                              }
```

> err: Could not retrieve catalog from
>   remote server: Error 400 on SERVER:
>   Duplicate definition: Exec[sleep 5] is
>   already defined in file
>   /etc/puppet/modules/common/manifests/defines/srv.pp
>   at line 4; cannot redefine at
>   /etc/puppet/modules/common/manifests/defines/srv.pp:4
>   on node testing.abc.def.com

**The correct define:**

```
define srv($enable="true",$ensure="running",$provider="runit",$hasstatus="true",$hasrestart="true"){

                exec {"sleep 5 for $name": command=>"sleep 5", path=>"/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin", before=>Service["$name"],}

                service{"$name":

                    enable=>$enable,
                    ensure=>$ensure,
                    provider=>$provider,
                    hasstatus=>$hasstatus,
                    hasrestart=>$hasrestart,
                }
                              }
```

So, why the error in the first case ? How am I duplicating a definition or in other words, if there was a single module using this define then would have the first define worked ? Maybe its the puppet terminology in the docs that has left me confused, but having written a ton of (working) modules and not understanding this sounds dangerous to me, hope I can get some clear answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resources in Puppet have to be unique, i. e. have to have a unique name.

In the described case, you had the resource `Exec["sleep 5"]` in your definition and every time you call  `srv` (it's basically the same as including a parameterized class), the resource `Exec["sleep 5"]` will also be included and thus the parser finds two or more resources with the same name.

By appending the `$name` of the definition to the name of your `Exec` resource, you make it unique. Well, at least *most likely* unique since when you have another resource with the same name (`Exec["sleep 5 for foo"`) somewhere else in your manifests, you'll run into this error again.